# Cross domain ajax request (jsonp) not working in Firefox (35.x) only

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cross-domain, jsonp

I have cross domain request like this:

```
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://mysite.ru/comp/ajax/api.php',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        data: { 
           data_1: data_1,
           opt: 'opt'
        },
        success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

On the server side I have code like:

```
$callback=$_REQUEST['callback'];

$url = "http://xn--b1afabpanwaea8aeld1f.xn--p1ai"; //this is russian site
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $url");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
echo $callback.'('.json_encode($data).')';
```

It works in Chrome, IE, but Firefox is not return response. In console I see this:

```
readyState:4
status:404
statusText:"error" ...
```

In the request header is no option "Origin" and query type is "plain". If I select in Developer panel in FF query and click "edit and send", then the request is successful, but in request header is added "Origin" and type set to "html".

Comment: do you see any error in console ?

Comment: no, only text from my debug (console.log(e);) 
"readyState:4
status:404
statusText:"error". It's all((

Comment: I can give links to real sites if needs.

Comment: sure that would help :)

Comment: Also it's little unclear as to what you're trying to do. are you trying jsonp or cors because they're two different things :)

Comment: site :http://соотечественники.рф/
form login pass in the top of the site.
alvka
111111

Comment: if you're just trying `jsonp` no need to make a CORS request, just remove the `crossDomain : true` in your $.ajax definition and remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header as well :)

Comment: Remove this parameters, but it still does not work.

Comment: when i try to access this url [http://mysite.ru/comp/ajax/api.php](http://mysite.ru/comp/ajax/api.php), its showing 404 error. Can you check if that url is correct ?

Comment: sorry, it was example))
http://www.russedina.ru/components/users/ajax/api.php - real url.

http://www.russedina.ru/components/users/ajax/api.php?callback=jQuery21305259917211184705_1423905533297&login=alvka&password=111111&opt=login&_=1423905533298
this is request from brouser

Comment: after logging into your site, what will trigger this Ajax call ? I'm not able to find any Ajax calls on page load

Comment: check smth like "preserve log" because after loggining page is reload((
may be discuss by skype?(

Comment: lets discuss the over [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70899/jquery-jsonp-cors)

Comment: I can't talk there((.
"You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. "

Comment: did you comment both these headers `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $url");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");` in your php ?

Comment: You're not preventing the default action of form submit. just add `return false;` in do_auth() after ajax call. I think it should resolve the issue :) Also there's a script error in common.js at line no 429, code is not properly commented. Correct that one as well

Comment: I add return, but nothing change. Error in common fix - it's my attempts))

Answer (score 0):

This request was hanging on submitting form, another one on href. Mozila can't send a request in these cases (only mozila). You'll hanging it only to static tags and if success make redirect or submit.
Now all working.